# Mule CXF unable to understand namespace

Tags: soap, mule, cxf

I've setup a Soap CXf service and when I send the following sample request it works

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="omitted" xmlns:ns1="omitted" xmlns:ns2="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:Notify>
      <ns1:EventMessage>
        <ns1:Message>
          test
        </ns1:Message>
      </ns1:EventMessage>
    </ns:Notify>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, when I try the following it fails

```html
<m:Notify xmlns:m="omitted" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="omitted">
  <jnet:EventMessage xmlns:jnet="omitted" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
    <jnet:Message>
      <CourtCaseEvent xmlns="omitted" xmlns:ansi="http://www.it.ojp.gov/jxdm/ansi_d20/1.0" xmlns:aopc="omitted" xmlns:j="http://www.it.ojp.gov/jxdm/3.0" xmlns:ncic="http://www.it.ojp.gov/jxdm/ncic_2000/1.0" xmlns:nibrs="http://www.it.ojp.gov/jxdm/nibrs_misc/1.0"
      xmlns:ref="omitted" xmlns:usps="http://www.it.ojp.gov/jxdm/usps_states/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" j:sourceIDText="1">
      </CourtCaseEvent>
    </jnet:Message>
  </jnet:EventMessage>
</m:Notify>
```

The error response from Mule is:

> "http://jnet.state.pa.us/message/jnet/EventMessageConsumer/1", the namespace on the "Notify" element, is not a valid SOAP version.

I've tried to set the namespace attribute of the CXf component to:

> http://jnet.state.pa.us/message/jnet/EventMessageConsumer/1

Without any luck. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding soap envelope markup to the message fixed the issue.